# Q: How to use ng-repeat onClick to execute function with param in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with template which has the list element `< ul> < / ul>` and it has `onClick` functionality. I get the input as an array to this directive. That array has two parameters they are name & functionname.

```
     $scope.actionsArray = [{
        functionName: $scope.releaseAllMovie,
        name: "Release All Movie"
      }, {
        functionName: $scope.releaseByDate,
        name: "Release By Date "
      }];
```

To execute this functionname i use another method inside directory. That is

```
       controller: function($scope){
            $scope.exec = function(func){
                func();
            };
        },
```

it works fine. Now i need to add two more options in it with function with parameter like below

```
     $scope.actionsArray = [{
        functionName: $scope.addVideos('clip'),
        name: "Add Video Clip"
      }, {
        functionName: $scope.addVideos('title'),
        name: "Add Movie Title"
      }];
```

but it is not working the way expected. While `onClick` on these items I get error like:

> TypeError: func is not a function

I have this code in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fv0XvGKuermc6yVhwxqC)

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because this line right here:

```
functionName: $scope.addVideos('clip')
```

Is going to immediately evaluate the function with that parameter and assign the result to `functionName`.

It sounds like what you want is a function to be executed with that specific parameter. Luckily, you can achieve this using the [`bind` function in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
functionName: $scope.addVideos.bind(this, 'clip')
```

This will actually create a new function that is pre-bound using those parameters.

**Here is a fork of your plunker showing the working code:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PboMINtDGmMNvDfuBjTd?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help Josh.